# Is this set $B$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ connected?

Tags: general-topology

Let $K=\left\{\left.\dfrac{1}{n}\ \right|\ n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$.

The set $A=(K\times[0,1])\cup([0,1]\times\{0\})$ is conected as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ but what about the set $B=A\cup\{(0,1)\}$, in this case it has no isolate point but it doesn't seem to be connected, so how do I prove that

Comment: Adding $(0,1)$ leaves the set the same? And please don't use the awful Munkres notation $0 \times 1$ for the point $(0,1)$. (I edited).

Comment: Adding the element $(0,1)$ changes the set, and I do prefer that notation since $(0,1)$ could be misunderstood as the interval.

Comment: $0 \in K$, so $(0,1) \in K \times [0,1] = A$. And $0 \times 1$ is a cartesian product of sets (in set theory). It looks too much like an algebraic term , so $0 \times 1 = 0$.

Comment: You probably need $0$ not to be in $K$.

Comment: That is right, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that $(0,1) \in \overline{A}$ so $B$ is connected by standard theorems:

if $A \subseteq B \subseteq \overline{A}$ and $A$ is connected then so is $B$.

Comment: I corrected the question, sorry, $0$ is not in $K$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $B \subset U \cup V$ where $U,V$ are open, non empty and disjoint.
Suppose $(0,1) \in U$ without loss of generality. Since $A$ is connected, it must
be entirely contained in either $U $ or $V$, hence we must have
$A \subset V$.

However, since $U$ is open, we must have $({1 \over n},1) \in U$ for $n$ sufficiently large, hence a contradiction.

Hence $B$ is connected.